# How to re-drag on once element is drop in drop container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-droppable

I am using jquery drag and drop plugin, I want to hide replica of drag element while dragging and once drag element is dropped on drop container it should be re-draggable.

My code is :

```
$(".dragButton").draggable({
           helper: 'clone'
 });

$(".dropBox").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover"
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

as your .dragButton has the same class it should still be dragable. otherwise use the callback function to make your dropped element dragable again